# What Strategy should be used in passport library of node.js

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am kinda new here. This is the first time I am implementing passport.js in my node.js project.
So far What I have done is use the Local Strategy and authenticate my login parameters with the passport library and by using JWT I also created the accessToken.

I just wanna ask that Is this the correct approach or do I need to use some other passport strategy to generate accessToken and refreshToken on its own like they do in Google Strategy.

This is the github link of the code.
https://github.com/nikhilgupta6532/Passport

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your repo. I think you are on the right track!

Some points.

You should not expose your jwt-secret to github repos. Use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

I understand that serializeUser and deserializeUser are not necessary for a jwt implementation. Only for cookie sessions?

You will need to generate a jwt besides the token supplied by google strategy.

Comment: I am using Local Strategy of Passport  not planning to use Google Strategy in my project. That's why I used JWT to generate Access Tokens.

Comment: Yeah, I see! But you could use JWT for google strategy as well.

Comment: In case, here is my implementation, may help. Local strategy,
 google, facebook authentication.
 (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/auth)